# how do I change Correlation Matrix gradient color and convert anti diagonal correlation to diagonal?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am able to generate a correlation matrix but then I want the gradient color to be changed. I would like to have lighter color for a lower value and darker color for higher value.

I would also appreciate if any can advice how do I flip the correlation diagonal from anti-diagonal to diagonal, please refer the screenshot.

[image]

```
cormat <- round(cor(test, use = "pairwise.complete.obs"),2)

melted_cormat <- melt(cormat)

ggplot(data = melted_cormat, aes(x=Var1, y=Var2, fill=value)) + geom_tile(color='white')
```

Comment: For the fill colors, `+ scale_fill_gradient(low="#56B1F7", high="#132B43")`. I've just reversed the default colors, but you can use whatever colors you wish. For the ordering, convert `Var1` to factor class (if it isn't a factor already) and reverse the ordering of the levels.

Comment: To reverse the levels: `melted_cormat$Var1 = with(melted_cormat, factor(Var1, levels=rev(unique(Var1))))`.

Comment: yes, both of these helped me achieve what I want. Thank you.